# How to fix "can't find gem railties" when gem says it is installed

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby

I tried to start a new Rails application, but got "can't find gem railties (=4.2.5)". Does it mean I have inconsistent versions?

I scoured all answers similar to the situation, but no solutions fixed the issue.

I'm on Mac OS. I installed using `sudo` after the fact thinking that was it as it fixed the issue for someone else. It's not that.

In one of the answers it suggested noting whether it was listed after the `gem list` command, which it was.

How do I fix this?

Comment: hello, could you add your `Gemfile/Gemfile.lock`, output of `gem list` and actual error?

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow. We don't care what your experience level is, we just care that you've researched and written a concise and clean question. Please read "[ask]" and "[mcve]" and the linked pages along with "[How much research effort is expected of Stack Overflow users?](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/261592)".

Comment: `"I installed w/ sudo..."` We need the exact command you used. Are you using rbenv or RVM as a sandbox manager? If so, _NEVER_ use `sudo` unless you understand what it does and why you'd want to use it. Run `gem env` and copy/paste the output into your question, formatted appropriately for readability.

Answer (score 0):

Issue resolved. For those who might have a similar issue. I started with the most recent version of rails, 5.1.0. but I needed another version for the assignment, 4.2.5. Initially I uninstalled the 4.2.5 and reinstalled, thinking this would resolve the issue. It did not. However, after getting sidetracked and trying a whole slew of things, I went back to the original idea and uninstalled BOTH 5.1.0 AND 4.2.5, then reinstalled both and the issue was then resolved.

I have no idea why this worked the way it did but it did. I hope this is helpful for those in a similar situation.

Answer (score 0):

`sudo` has to be used for invoking `rails` command, since it was installed using root privileges - this should solve the problem.